# OpenGL ES 3.0 - Jagged Edges When Rendering Into Retained Color Attachment

Tags: ios, opengl-es, fragment-shader, opengl-3

Using **OpengGL ES 3.0** on **iOS**, I want to use one framebuffer object (FBO) with 2 color attachments (*A0*, *A1*) to render object(s) *a0* into *A0* and *a1* into *A1*. The texture for *A1* is retained and reused in the next frame(s) while *A0* is invalidated (and cleared).

The problem is that when rendering into *A1* jagged artefacts (mostly along the object edges) are created, c.f. attached image (*Color Attachment 1 = A0*, *Color Attachment 2 = A1*).

[image: GPU Snapshot in Xcode - Artefacts in Color Attachment 1]

I inspected the GL state and made sure that the correct FBO is currently bound and that there are no GL_ERRORs and that GL_MAX_COLOR_ATTACHMENTS is 4.
I create a FBO with 2 color attachments as follows:

```
// Assuming the FBO and the 2 requried textures were correctly generated

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _fbo);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, _fbo_tex[0], 0);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_TEXTURE_2D, _fbo_tex[1], 0);

// glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) returns GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE
```

The vertex shader:

```
#version 300 es
uniform mat4 modelviewProjectionMatrix;
in vec4 position;

void main() {
    gl_Position = modelviewProjectionMatrix * position;
}
```

The fragment shader to render into *A0*:

```
#version 300 es
uniform lowp vec4 colorIn;
layout(location = 0) out lowp vec4 colorOut;

void main() {
    colorOut = colorIn;
}
```

The fragment shader to render into *A1*:

```
#version 300 es
uniform lowp vec4 colorIn;
layout(location = 1) out lowp vec4 colorOut;

void main() {
    colorOut = colorIn;
}
```

And here's the render code:

```
// Assuming the correct vertex array is bound
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, _fbo);
{
    glUseProgram(_program_for_a0);
    const GLenum attachments[] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0};
    glDrawBuffers(1, attachments);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Draw a0 into GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0
}
{
    glUseProgram(_program_for_a1);
    const GLenum attachments[] = {GL_NONE, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1};
    glDrawBuffers(2, attachments);
    // No glClear() call

    // Draw a1 into GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1
}
```

And here the invalidation:

```
const GLenum attachments[] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0};
glInvalidateFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 1, attachments);
```

In case this is helpful information, the artefacts seem to be caused due to some tiling mechanism as they are 32x32 pixel blocks.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a driver state management bug to me. Given that you never seem to render to attachment 0 and attachment 1 at the same time, why not just use two framebuffer objects?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The reason for this implementation is that switching between color attachments gives a significant performance improvement over switching between FBOs.

Comment: Usual render order would be to render one FBO to completion (all draw calls) in a single glBindFramebuffer() followed by N draws, and then render the other to completion in another single glBindFramebuffer() followed by N draws. The only cost here should a single writeout of color attachment 0 to main memory between the two FBOs. If you keep flipping back and forth between the two then, yes that's going to hurt horribly because you keep flushing tile contents back to memory.

Comment: See here: https://community.arm.com/graphics/b/blog/posts/mali-performance-2-how-to-correctly-handle-framebuffers .. for general advice related to how to handle framebuffers with tile-based hardware.